# MongoDB: Ist there a possiblity to match a field containing a regular expression against a string in a $match stage in an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am currently trying to optimize some queries by using aggregation pipelines. Now I want to have a $match stage that filters out most of the collection documents in order to speed up the following stages.
The problem I am facing is that the documents in the collection do contain fields that represent regular expressions.
I now want to match strings against these regular expressions (preferably in the first $match stage).

This is how my current solution looks. But I am not really happy with this in terms of readability and probably performance.

```
[
    {$match: {
    name: "docName"
        }
    },
    {$addFields: {
    fieldAMatches: {$regexMatch: {input: "ABC", regex: '$fieldA'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {$match: {
    fieldAMatches: true
        }
    }
]
```

A sample dataset would look the following:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": ".*"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": "AB.*"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": "AB.+"
    },
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": "BAC"
    }
]
```

The result contains the following documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": ".*"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": "AB.*"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "docName",
        "fieldA": "AB.+"
    },
]
```

Comment: If you provide a couple of sample documents and show us the expected result of your query, I am sure we can advise you on how to optimize it.

Comment: @codemonkey I edited my post and it now hopefully contains all the needed information. Feel free to comment again if something is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/exp/) do achieve this, from the docs:

> $match takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. $match does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

Meaning by using `$expr` we can include aggregation expression (and in our case `$regexMatch`) in `$match` stage like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "docName",
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "ABC",
          regex: "$fieldA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LlEcdfEy11Z)

Comment: Thanks. That works almost as expected. Maybe one additional question: I observed a better performance when wrapping both the name and the regexMatch into and $and. Is it because only stops evaluating the whole condition when one subcondition failed this way?

Comment: That's an interesting question and i'm can't really answer that. if you wan't to investigate it further i would first look into the explained results to see if there's a different winning plan chosen by the cursor to fetch the results.